# MissingMethodException using MS Solver Foundation v2.1

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

I am new to MS Solver Foundation and am trying to run the CompactQuasiNewtonSolver from C# but I am getting an error.

The only code I have inside my main method is this:

```
CompactQuasiNewtonSolver solver = new CompactQuasiNewtonSolver(1);
```

but I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Solvers.CompactQuasiNewtonSolver..ctor(Int32)'. at VAR.Program.Main(String[] args)

Anyone has an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are invoking the CompactQuasiNewtonSolver incorrectly. You should probably just use the constructor that takes zero arguments as described in the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg248762%28v=VS.93%29.aspx).